# Ошибка AJAX File-Uploader: Файл не загрузился

Tags: javascript, ajax

Использую плагин [AJAX File-Uploader](http://falbar.ru/article/id/115) для загрузки файлов на сервер.
Файлы на сервер зугружаются, но постоянно выходит сообщение об ошибке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему появляется это сообщение, можно ли поправить?
http://mn27.ru/www/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас задваивание содержимого ответа происходит. Вместо возврата

```
{"success":true}
```

с сервера приходит

```
{"success":true}{"success":true}
```

что уже является невалидным JSON.

На сервере проверяйте правильность формирования ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ очень помог.